# Http response is detected but view is not updated using Angular 6.x

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using Angular 6.x to create a login page. I have used HTTP Error intercepter to capture all HTTP issues. Here is how my error intercepter and app.module looks like

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

```
/**
 * Intercepts the HTTP responses, and in case that an error/exception is thrown, handles it
 * and extract the relevant information of it.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    /**
     * Intercepts an outgoing HTTP request, executes it and handles any error that could be triggered in execution.
     * @see HttpInterceptor
     * @param req the outgoing HTTP request
     * @param next a HTTP request handler
     */
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(errorResponse => {
                let errMsg: string;
                if (errorResponse instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    const err = errorResponse.message || JSON.stringify(errorResponse.error);
                    errMsg = `${errorResponse.status} - ${errorResponse.statusText || ''} Details: ${err}`;
                } else {
                    errMsg = errorResponse.message ? errorResponse.message : errorResponse.toString();
                }
                console.log(errMsg)
                return throwError(errorResponse);
            }));
    }
}

/**
 * Provider POJO for the interceptor
 */
export const ErrorInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true,
};
```

```

I have added the same in app.module.ts

```

```
providers: [
    DataService,
    DatePipe,
    ErrorInterceptorProvider,
    DataBaseService,
],
```

```

When i perform a login call which fails, error is captured properly and i come back to the error handler in component

```

```
login(args: EventData) {
    ..... Some code

    //call login service
    this.service.login(this.user).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log("token: ", result.token);

        .... Some code on success

    }, (error) => {
        this.processing = false;
        this.isError = true;
        loginBtn.isEnabled = true;
        switch (error.status.toString()) {
            case "401":
                lbl.text = localize("invalid_user_pass");
                break;
            case "200":
                lbl.text = localize("server_error");
                break;
            default:
                lbl.text = localize("invalid_user_pass");
                break;
        }
        this.cleanUser();
    });
}
```

```

Problem is that even though i am updating the variables in component, my view does not reflect those changes. I found [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235284/http-requests-made-from-ngxs-state-doesnt-get-detected-by-angular-zone-related) link for very similar problem w.r.t. NgZone. I feel that even i am facing similar issue but unable to get solution currently. I tried returning the values via ngZone in error intercept method. However problem was not solved. Can someone help in identifying the root cause? Since this problem looks to be purely Angular related issue, tagging Angularjs along with Nativescript tags.

Comment: `lbl.text` is double binded to an html element, right?

Comment: `ngZone` is only needed if you run functions outside of the angular environment, otherwise it isnt neccessary

Comment: Please share the complete code along with your HTML, which component and what part of data is not being updated?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Yes. Its done using ngModel

Comment: @mast3rd3mon In the link which i have provided, its given that ngrx runs the function in different zone. Similarly here also we are working with RxJS, which might be running it in different zone. Hence the thought of relating these 2 issues.

Comment: rxjs typically runs inside the angular environment, you would only need to use ngzone if you ran code outside the angular classes